# Trouble with helpers and db calls

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Just started to learn a Meteor and stuck with a silly problem. I have a collection "Images" and i trying to get one random image from her. But in the browser's console it's says that "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined", but if type a db's "findOne" method in the console there is a record that i wanted. 
A client code:

```
    Template.main.helpers({
        img: function () {
            return Images.findOne({rand: {$gte: Math.random()}}).url;
        }
    });
```

Collection:

```
    Images = Meteor.Collection('images');
```

On a server's side i've got simple fixtures for initial tests

```
    if(Images.find().count() === 0){
        Images.insert({url: "http://domain.com/test1.jpg", rand: Math.random()});
        Images.insert({url: "http://domain.com/test2.jpg", rand: Math.random()});
        Images.insert({url: "http://domain.com/test3.jpg", rand: Math.random()});
    }
```

And simple template:

```
    <head>
      <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      {{> main}}
    </body>

    <template name="main">
      {{img}}
    </template>
```

P.S. I'm working under the Win 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm going to assume that the images are published to the client. You should verify that `Images.find().count() > 0` is `true` in your browser console (not in your template code).

Next, you should read about how to add guards to your template code to fix the error you are seeing. [This article](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) should explain what you need to know.

Finally, unless you actually need `rand` on your documents, there are better ways to accomplish a random selection. Your question says you are looking for *one* image, but it's possible that 1 or 0 could be returned with your code. Instead you could use the built-in [Random](http://docs.meteor.com/#random) package. Give this a try:

```js
Template.main.helpers({
  img: function() {
    var image = Random.choice(Images.find().fetch());
    return image && image.url;
  }
});
```

---

Although, I think it makes more sense to return the image object:

```js
Template.main.helpers({
  image: function() {
    return Random.choice(Images.find().fetch());
  }
});
```

And then select the `url` in your template (no guards are needed in this case):

```html
<template name="main">
  <img src="{{image.url}}">
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with your assumptions when you load a template. When your web page has loaded on the web browser, it won't necessarily have any data in it (your Images.findOne() query could return `null`)

You just need to take account of this possibility

```
var image = Images.findOne({rand: {$gte: Math.random()}});
return image && image.url
```